# Regular Expression Finding a pattern that contains a variable and matches same variable that may contain hyphen,comma,apostrophe, and white space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable that contains a compound word (ex. cocacola, pancakes). I'm having trouble finding a regex pattern which will use that particular variable in the pattern itself and will find a match in something like coca-cola, or pan cakes.

I was thinking `[variableName,+-]+`, but that will find matches with each letter/character in the compound word of the variable, since it is enclosed in character set.

Comment: Let's see some sample data. `(?:variableName|[,+-])+` might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function regex_from(word) {
    return new RegExp(word.split("").map(x => x.replace(/\W/g, '\\$1')).join("[\\-,'\\s]?"));
}

const regex = regex_from('cocacola');

console.log(regex.test('coca-cola'));
console.log(regex.test('coc aco la'));
console.log(regex.test('cocoalco'));
```

Idea: Split input word into single characters (and escape them for use in a regex if necessary), join them back into a single string using a separator of `[\-,'\s]?`, and treat the whole thing as a regex.

For example, `abc` becomes `/a[\-,'\s]?b[\-,'\s]?c/`, which matches e.g. `abc`, `a-b-c`, `a b'c`, `ab,c`, etc.